# add a class atribute to an actionLink (HTML Helper) in asp.net mvc5

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add a class attribute to an actionlink and I use this sintax

```
@Html.ActionLink("ادامه مطلب", "Detaile", new { @class = "MyCssClass" } )
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", CONTROLLERNAME, null, new { @class= "yourCSSclass"}
```

maybe  **you are missing the Controller name**